# VS 2010 RDLC -Desginer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, rdlc

We have a VS2008 solution with a project that had RDLC files. We generate them dynamically in code, and don't need the viewer.

However, when we converted to VS2010, when I open the .rdlc i don't get the designer, it just opens as XML. Even if I create a new rdlc from scratch in 2010, it opens in xml, not with the designer. Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Reporting Services development is done in Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS), which uses the Visual Studio shell. The Visual Studio 2010 shell is not yet supported. You'll have to edit the report in BIDS using the VS2008 shell.

Check the second note [here](http://You%27ll%20have%20to%20edit%20the%20report%20in%20BIDS%20using%20the%20VS2008%20shell.) for more info.

Comment: Turned out I just needed to restart VS. When I opened the rdlc file the second time it prompted me to convert it to 2008. After doing the conversion I could use the designer in VS 2010. Fun....